# game currency convert: math efficiency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

For variables:4 text views named `diamondText`, `goldText`, `silverText`, and `bronzeText`;money variable `unsigned int money`;and an `NSTimer`, every .1 sec,runs function:

```
-(void)updateMoney{
    money++;
    bronzeText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",money];
    silverText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",money%10];
    goldText.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",money%100];
    diamondText.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",money%1000];
}
```

Given that my currency is diamond = 10 gold = 10 silver = 10 bronze = 1;

**What would be most efficient way to calculate and display the money labels? How would you store this variable, with GameCenter and NSDictionary or GameCenter and something else?**

---

More details below:

To clarify: bronze has the last 2 numbers, silver has the next 2 numbers, and so on.

I understand I could use 4 ints or an array, but i would rather try to use this method, unless theres a much more efficient way.

Example: When `money = 1000`;`bronzeText = nothing`, `silverText = 10`,`goldText = nothing`, `diamondText = nothing`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off...if you're giving each coin two digits, then your math is off.  If you mod 10 everything, then each coin only gets one digit.  But you're not even doing that quite right; the math doesn't take into account the value of the coins, or ignore the coins you've already accounted for, or any of that.  Say you had 1371 money...with your current math, bronze=1371, silver=1, gold=71, and diamond=371.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you had in mind.

You might try something like

```
int bronze = money % 100;
int silver = (money / 100) % 100;
int gold = (money / 10000) % 100;
int diamond = money / 1000000;
```

Now, if you have 1371 money, you have bronze=71, silver=13, gold=0, diamond=0.

As for updating the views, with the bronze, you're pretty much going to always have to update that -- any change will affect it.  If you're always incrementing by one, though, you only have to update the next higher coin when the current coin's count is 0.  For example, if you had 2799 and updated, bumping your money up to 2800, you'd now have bronze=0, so you'd update silver to 28.  Since 28 != 0, though, the gold wouldn't need updating, so you wouldn't even bother with diamond.

You only have to update it *when the money changes*, though.  So doing it on collision makes a lot more sense than on a timer.  :)

Comment: Personally, i'd say like `bronzeText.text = ...; if (bronze != 0) return; silverText.text = ...; if (silver != 0) return;` and so on.  The updates would be similar to what you have, except that instead of doing the math in there, you'd use the variables i mentioned above.